# SQL Server CE 4 very poor performance on XP SP3

Tags: performance, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce-4, sqlperformance

I have a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database with Entity Framework 4.3 and Encryption enabled with Platform Default mode and this is its connection string:

```
Data Source={Database File};Password={MyPassword}; Encryption Mode=Platform Default;Persist Security Info=False;Locale Identifier=1065
```

When I execute a simple query like authenticating a user by their user name and password, under Windows 7 or 8 it works perfectly with a reasonable performance. But if I run it on a Windows XP Service Pack 3 environment it executes the query incredibly slow. Takes about 1 or sometimes 2 minutes to authenticate the user.

- XP Computer configuration is: Intel Pentium Celeron 2.8 MHz and 512MB RAM.
- Windows 7 configuration is the same except that it has 1GB of RAM.

At the end I want to have a small database like the SQL Server CE with a good encryption support that works with EF 4.3. If any other database engines with this features exists and can solve this poor performance, it could solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check few things like..

Is your database encrypted?

Do you open and close connections, or do you keep a connection object open for the lifetime of the app?

For more detail follow the related thread on stackoverflow itself ..you might find the solution

[SqlCe opens slow under a limited user account in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697308/sqlce-opens-slow-under-a-limited-user-account-in-windows-xp/11699440#11699440)

Comment: As I mentioned it is encrypted and I open and close the connection prior and after the authentication request.